# Approximating Pi within error function

Tags: python-3.x

So the question I'm having problems with is:

> The mathematical
>   constant π (pi) is an irrational number with value approximately
>   `3.1415928...` The precise value of π is equal to the following infinite sum: `π = 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 - 4/11 + ...` We can get a good
>   approximation of `π` by computing the sum of the first few terms. Write
>   a function `approxPi(error)` that takes as a parameter a floating point value
>   error and approximates the constant `π` within error by computing the
>   above sum, term by term, until the absolute value of the difference
>   between the current sum and the previous sum (with one fewer terms) is
>   no greater than error. Once the function finds that the difference is
>   less than error, it should return the new sum.

Example of correct input: `approxPi(0.01)` should return `3.1465677471829556`

My code:

```
def approxPi(error):
    i=5 #counter for list appending
    lst = [4,(-4/3)] #list values will be appended to
    currentSum = sum(lst) #calcs sum of the list
    previousSum = sum(lst[:len(lst)-1]) #calcs sum of list with one less term
    while abs(currentSum - previousSum) > error: #while loop for error value
        if len(lst) % 2==0: #alternates appending positive or negative value
            lst.append((4/i)) #appends to list
        else:
            lst.append((-4/i))
        i+=2 #increments counter
    return currentSum  #returns sum of the whole list once error value has been reached
```

When I run the code I get stuck in the loop until memory usage reaches 100% and my system locks up. Any tips on what I am doing wrong? This is a homework problem so please don't just post an answer.

Comment: Hint: when do you change either currentSum or previousSum?  But SO isn't for giving hints, really, we're a Q&A website, where the questions and answers are supposed to help other people too.  Giving hints instead of answers doesn't really advance that goal.

Comment: The problem is most likely the appending to the list, it will grow way too large quickly. Try printing the error at each iteration (and the iteration itself) to follow what happens until it hangs.

Comment: Why are you keeping a list of all approximations when you only need the current and the previous. 'Tis an awful waste of space and time.

Comment: currentSum and previousSum change as new terms get appended, correct? I understand you DSM. Hopefully I can get pointed to the right direction and then post my successful answer.

Comment: A list made the most sense to me when starting the problem but I'm beginning to think I need to do it another way. I was fixated on doing it this way

Comment: I just cobbled a non-list form of this and remembered how slowly that [Leibniz series converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80#Convergence) Getting to 3.141592 took 20 million terms; no wonder you were running out of core.

Comment: @DSM I think of the OP answers his own question then it would be a reasonable resource for future searchers.

Comment: I see msw. I'm going to work on a solution to the problem that doesn't involve using a list. Thank you